# Confusion in upgrading php in CentOS 5.5 / nginx

Tags: centos, php, nginx

I was trying to upgrade from php 5.3 to php 5.5.x on my CentOS 5.5 vps running nginx.

I ran yum upgrade php command.

When I run php -V from command line, I get this output:

```
[root@ns1 ~]# php -v
**PHP 5.5.1** (cli) (built: Jul 24 2013 18:16:31)
```

However when I run a test_page.php with this code, **it says php 5.3.14**

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong, because both are supposed to show same version isn't it?

To be sure, I also want to find if there are multiple installations of php, but I don't know how to do it, that's why I am posting this question here.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this from the Command line:

```
php -i | grep "ENV\[\"_\""
```

Should look like this

```
_ENV["_"] => /usr/bin/php
```

Then run test_page.php  and Look for that *ENV["*"] block. If the two are different, then your web server is pointing to a different PHP then the default from the command line.

If your Distro supports it, you can try to locate any PHP instances

```
locate php | grep -E "\/php$"
```

Sample output

```
/usr/bin/php
/usr/include/php
/usr/lib/php
/usr/share/php
```

And you can gather I only have /usr/bin/php but you can review your list to see which are actually PHP binaries